# Requirements for Creating A New Coded UI Testing Project In VS2017 Enterprise

Tags: coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-2017

I've just installed *Visual Studio 2017* **Enterprise** (15.0.26228.4 D15RTWSVC) with .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055. I cannot add a new coded UI test project to a new solution because I cannot find that project type in the 'New Project' dialog. I assume it's because I didn't install some optional module when I was installing Visual Studio.

Which optional module do I need to install to be able to add new Coded UI test projects to solutions in VS2017 Enterprise?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise on the installer's Individual components tab I see this:

[image: A check box for Coded UI test]

It appears to be an optional component.

Comment: Note that this option is only available in VS 2017 Enterprise

Comment: Thanks a lot! This made my day!

Comment: This was a lot harder to find than it should be. But THANK YOU saved my life.

Comment: I saw a post (http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/e58dd8b3-bdcd-4415-9732-1d6be8f14366?category=vstest) that says that Enterprise and Ultimate version both support Coded UI Test in 2017.

Comment: @amalgamate There is no VS 2017 Ultimate (there was for some older VS versions, but that changed with 2015 IIRC). Enterprise is the "top" edition.

Comment: If it's optional, does it mean it may not even be available in the next version of Visual Studio?

Comment: @RayCheng the C++ compiler & tools is also optional... and that's older than .NET. Being optional has no barring on future support.

Comment: @RayCheng Yup, MS now shows notice confirming that Coded UI tests are being deprecated and that Selenium should be used instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-html5-controls-in-coded-ui-tests?view=vs-2017